# Termination Error in Eclipse when trying to process large array

Tags: c++

So for my assignment, I have to process a very large amount of data. I have to take 832 binary files, pull out their info and put it into an array so that I can process what's in the array from there.

Doing so gives me the error: 
terminated (exit value: -1,073,741,571).

It's not my compiler, I spent 30 minutes verifying that MinGW is correctly set in my PATH.

The array for my data looks like this:

```
float fullDataArray[63][63][832];
```

And I am filling it as such:

```
for(int a = 0; a < 100; a++){

        for(int b = 0; b < 16; b++){

            for(int c = 0; c < 52; c++){

                ifstream inputFile( "Beaufort_Sea_diffw"+weeks[c]+"y"+years[b]+"+landmask", ios::in | ios::binary );
                //cout<<"Beaufort_Sea_diffw"+weeks[c]+"y"+years[b]+"+landmask"<<endl;
                float dataIn = 0;
                for(int i = 0; i < 63; i++){
                    for(int j = 0; j < 63; j++){
                        inputFile.read( (char*)&dataIn, 4 ); // Read 4 bytes of data
                        fullDataArray[i][j][a] = dataIn;

                        //cout << "Value read in from Beaufort_Sea_diffw03y1990+landmask: " << dataIn << endl;
                    }
                }
                inputFile.close();
            }
        }
    }
```

And any attempt to run it crashes. I have tried removing the nested for-loop that fills the array and that allows it to work. I have also tried reducing the size of the 3rd dimension and that allows it to work. I think it must be too much data, which I don't know how to fix. I am required to process exactly this much data for the assignment, and was told that a 3d array could be done for this. My other classmates have their code working, and they admit that it takes a few minutes of processing to complete. Eclipse won't even try. It just quits.

Comment: `fullDataArray` is 63 *63 * 832 `floats`. That's about 13 MB. Don't throw that on the stack. Most desktop systems have a stack of 1 to 10 MB in size.

Comment: How do I know that's on the stack? When you see a weird number like -1,073,741,571, convert it to hex (C00000FD) and see if you recognize it as a common error code. If you don't recognize it, check with Mssr. Google. He'll tell you that it's Windows reporting a Stack Overflow.